# Google App Engine Android Tutorial method is undefined

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, undefined-function

The tutorial that Google gives for the App Engine is pretty straight forward copy paste code that they give you to st up the program. I was on the part where you copy the code from a file called MainActivity.01 to the MainActivity file in the program. After doing so there was an error saying that the method was undefined however it is defined under the backend project, but is not defined in the library I created under the client project. If anyone is familiar with the tutorial I'm on step Modify the Client Application step. The link is [here](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/)

the code that is giving me problems is

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
  CheckIn checkin = new CheckIn();

  checkin.setPlaceId("StoreNo123");//problem**************************

  Checkinendpoint.Builder builder = new Checkinendpoint.Builder(
      AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
      null);

  builder = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(builder);

  Checkinendpoint endpoint = builder.build();


  try {
    endpoint.insertCheckIn(checkin).execute();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return null;
}`
```

the class the method is defined in in the backend project

```
package com.google.samplesolutions.mobileassistant;

import java.util.Date;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class CheckIn {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
    private String placeId;
    private String userEmail;
    private Date checkinDate;

    public Key getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getPlaceId() {
        return placeId;
    }
    public void setPlaceId(String placeId) {
        this.placeId = placeId;
    }

    public String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }
    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }

    public Date getCheckinDate() {
        return checkinDate;
    }
    public void setCheckinDate(Date date) {
        checkinDate = date;
    }
}
```

and the class under the client project

```
package com.google.samplesolutions.mobileassistant.checkinendpoint.model;

/**
 * Model definition for CheckIn.
 *
 * <p> This is the Java data model class that specifies how to   parse/serialize into the JSON that is
 * transmitted over HTTP when working with the checkinendpoint. For a detailed explanation see:
 * <a href="http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/JSON">http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/JSON</a>
 * </p>
 *
 * @author Google, Inc.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public final class CheckIn extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson {

  @Override
  public CheckIn set(String fieldName, Object value) {
    return (CheckIn) super.set(fieldName, value);
  }

  @Override
  public CheckIn clone() {
    return (CheckIn) super.clone();
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `checkin.set("placeId", "StoreNo123");` ?

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm.